# Finding matrices which P is null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let P is set all vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in R^{4}$ for which $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4=0$

a) Find one base of subspace $P^{\bot}$

b) Prove that P is subspace of $R^{4}$ then construct matrices which P is null space.

a) I found base $(1,1,1,1)$ that is easy
b) I know how to prove that $P$ is subspace, but I do not know if my matrix is good, because what means that P is null space, does that mean that for every vector $x\in P$ $Ax=0$. So matrices $A$ are

> A=$\begin{bmatrix}
>     1& 1& 1& 1\\
>     1& 1& 1& 1\\
>     1 & 1& 1& 1\\
>     1 & 1& 1& 1
>    \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are fine, but I don't know if you are expected to find just one matrix whose null space is $P$. The question says 'matrices'.

Answer (score 0):

a) The vector $(1,1,1,1)$ is indeed the basis vector for $P^{\bot}$. Just a warning that the question may implicitly also require you to *prove* your claim, which is not difficult in this particular case, but may cause loss of points.

b) Your matrix is ok, but you could also just have the matrix $[1,1,1,1]$ which has the same nullspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's correct, a basis for $P$ is $(1,-1,0,0),(1,0,-1,0),(1,0,0,-1)$ and $(1,1,1,1)$ is a basis for $P^{\perp}$, for point "b" more in general matrices $A$ are n-by-4 matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a& a& a& a\\
    a& a& a& a\\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots\\
    a & a& a& a
   \end{bmatrix}$$

with $a \neq 0$.